# Laravel to Basic PHP Login Integration, Working! But Fail to Set Session

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, session, laravel-5.3

So I'm trying to use laravel-based login table, which is the hash that I can't even compare it with basic php hash login. No, you can't make hash exactly look like laravel. But I use the `remember_token` that is come from `users` table.

Here is the code on my laravel view:

```
<form action="http://localhost/log/index.php" method="post">
       <input type="hidden" value="{{ Auth::user()->remember_token }}" name="wex">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Check</button>
</form>
```

As you can see, I'm trying to POST `remember_token` value, that will received on my `http://localhost/log/index.php` as variable.

Index.php (Not use Laravel):

```
<?php
    include "koneksi.php";

    if (isset($_POST['wex'])) {
        $token = $_POST['wex'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE remember_token = '". $token ."'" ;
        $result = mysqli_query($db_link,$query);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) != 1) {
            header("Location: http://localhost/laralearn/public/login");
        }

        session_start();
        $_SESSION['user'] = "member";
    }
    else{

        if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
            header("Location: http://localhost/laralearn/public/login");
        }
    }


?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Customer</title>
</head>
<body>

    <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" border="1" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">If you can see this table, you are logged in. </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Username: 
        </td>
        <td><?php

        while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "$data[name]";         
        }


        ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Token:
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $token; ?>       
        </td>
    </tr>

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

The variable and page redirect if the `remember_token` isn't valid (working), but I can't set the session. The page keep redirecting to Laravel site.

Can you tell me where am I doing something wrong? It would be nice if you explain it and tell me what the code should look like.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have laravel on the server? If so you should be able to bootstrap (start) laravel and use its authentication

Comment: I'm not trying to start session on Laravel, i'm trying to start session on nonlaravel website, based on post from laravel site.

Comment: I understood, I was just saying if this non laravel script was on the same server the easiest thing to do is "hook into" laravel and use its methods for auth etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use in Laravel session like below:

```
Session::set('user', "member");
```

Get session variable:

```
Session::get('user');
```

Comment: I'm not trying to start session on Laravel, i'm trying to start session on nonlaravel website.